# How to make long operations on list item click but not on UI thread?

Tags: android, sqlite, onclicklistener, listview-adapter

I have a list view, in which, every item contains 3 buttons, one for saving in database, and the other two should open new fragments. I have implemented OnClickListener for which of the buttons in the getView() method of the adapter. When the user clicks the save button, I want to write item in database. Since, writing to database is considered to be long operation, and it should not be done on UI thread, I would like to ask how to do it? Should I make my own thread or can I use service or async task? Here is the code from getView:

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.top_tracks_artists_item_layout,parent,false);

        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.trackName= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.top_tracks_item_name);

        viewHolder.trackInfo= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.top_tracks_item_info);
        viewHolder.trackInfo.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.trackInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("try", "Info clicked "  +position);
            }
        });

        viewHolder.trackFavourite= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.top_tracks_item_favourite);
        viewHolder.trackFavourite.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.trackFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("try", "favourites  clicked " +position);
            }
        });

        viewHolder.trackWatch= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.top_tracks_item_watch);
        viewHolder.trackWatch.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.trackWatch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("try", "Watch clicked "  +position);
    //here I want to save to database

            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder= (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.trackName.setText((String)tracks.get(position).toString());

    return convertView;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Async task or handlers to achieve that. Here see the below tutorial and refernce in the given link

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: But can I define the Async Task in the adapter?

Comment: Create or Define a Asynctask in your adapter or activity. and on click of the Item just execute the Async function....

Answer (score 0):

You can try with AsyncTask, also consider showing a spinner while saving the image if you like to show the progress of saving. Once your saving to DB done send the status done and dismiss your progress bar. In case you need some sample on how to do it, refer below link.
[Add listener in AsyncTask when called postExecute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641843/add-listener-in-asynctask-when-called-postexecute/35642070#35642070)

Answer (score 0):

Use Android AsyncTask for background tasks. Usage is like this ;

```
    private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Service**

> Not bounded to the Activity lifecycle , services will run even if your application is closed/switched/Config Changes
>
> Operation to be performed by service Runs in the Main(UI) Thread,
> So  you need to create a Java-Thread inside onStartCommand() method

**Intent Service**

> Not bounded to the Activity lifecycle , services will run even if your application is closed/switched/Config Changes
>
> Operation to be performed by IntentService runs in "single worker thread"
> Note : Since it runs on "single worker thread" thus is not suited for Multithreaded Applications

**AsyncTask**

> Bounded to Activity lifecycle , services will not run if your application is closed/switched/Config Changes,So you need to take these on consideration while using AsyncTask